# C# POST request response 400 when 200 in Postman

Tags: c#, postman, httprequest, httpclient, basic-authentication

I need to send a POST request with usage of HttpClient, what i have right now:

```
    [Route("RegisterTransaction")]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> RegisterTransaction()
    {

        var httpClient = this._httpClientFactory.CreateClient();

        try
        {

            string jsonData = "{\"sessionId\":\"1\"," +
                               "\"merchantId\":00000," +
                               "\"amount\":2137," +
                               "\"currency\":\"PLN\"," +
                                "\"crc\":\"xxxxxxxx\"}";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
            SHA384 shaM = new SHA384Managed();
            var hashResult = shaM.ComputeHash(byteArray);
            string stringHashResult = BitConverter.ToString(hashResult).Replace("-", String.Empty).ToLower();


            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                // Set the base address and headers for the request
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                // Set the Basic Authentication header
                var authValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{merchantId}:{clientSecret}"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authValue);


                var urlReturn = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("http://sample.com/");

                var payload = 
                    "{" +
                    "\"merchantId\":" + $"{merchantId}" + "," +
                    "\"posId\":" + $"{merchantId}" + "," +
                    "\"sessionId\":" + "\"1\"" + "," +
                    "\"amount\":" + "2137" + "," +
                    "\"currency\":" + "\"PLN\"" + "," +
                    "\"description\":" + "\"test_from_c#\"" + "," +
                    "\"email\":" + "\"sample@gmail.com\"" + "," +
                    "\"country\":" + "\"PL\"" + "," +
                    "\"language\":" + "\"pl\"" + "," +
                    "\"urlReturn\":" + $"\"{urlReturn}\"" + "," +
                    "\"timeLimit\":" + "15" + "," +
                    "\"waitForResult\":" + "true" + "," +
                    "\"shipping\":" + "0" + "," +
                    "\"sign\":" + $"\"{stringHashResult}\"" +
                    "}";

                var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                // Send the POST request and get the response
                var response = await client.PostAsync(uriPath, content);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

Problem is that, this code generates response 400:

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent, Headers:{  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16000000; includeSubDomains; preload;  Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store  Pragma: no-cache  Date: Sun, 18 Dec 2022 19:52:14 GMT  Connection: close  Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=20417919ff332939962473ac49ab1f1e; path=/; secure; HttpOnly  Set-Cookie: akaalb_Sandbox=~op=sandbox:sandbox-dc1|~rv=60~m=sandbox-dc1:0|~os=352131486e59fe329be9d171af3005ed~id=903a75e16940cf8c12e4c2e79ee82d78; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None  DC: DC1  Content-Type: application/json  Content-Length: 40  Expires: Sun, 18 Dec 2022 19:52:14 GMT}, Trailing Headers:{}}
```

with a little to no information usefull to me, while this exact same request sended from Postman is resulting in response 200.

My question is: Why is that?

Why this same payload with these same headers generating different responses? I've checked json payload and it is 100% correct, also generated hashes and username and password in header. What am I missing?

Comment: You can try using postman feature that autoconverts HTTP request to sample code snippets with your desired language. anyways please put more information about the api and what it expects from you so we can help detecting the problem.

Comment: check if you are making the request in postman with https:// if so that could be the problem with your c# code and try changing that instead of http://

Comment: Could we see the Postman payload? Is `merchantId` a number or a string, because if its a string, it needs quotes. Also, I would check http/https between the two. Also, look at the headers in Postman and compare to the headers you're sending.

Comment: @VicF was correct, it was about headers, to be exact "Accept-Encoding" header